# Shocked while main panel breaker was off

Tags: electrical-panel

Yesterday I pulled a new wire to an existing breaker in our electric panel. Obvious first step was to turn off the main breaker, which I verified with a non-contact voltage tester (confirmed working before turning off the main breaker, and again after turning the power back on).

While trying to remove the old earth wire from the main panel, my elbow touched a wall and I got shocked.

How is this possible? House was built in 1991, and the main panel is a Nova Line built by Westinghouse. Main breaker is shielded off in its own part, no live wires exposed.

Comment: Perhaps you simply banged your funny-bone? :-)

Comment: Lol, I wish... It was just a moderate shock, but yeah.

Comment: Anything in your house that could generate or store power? Solar array, generator, hydro dam, RTG?

Comment: Do you have a clamp-on ammeter, or can you get your hands on one?

Comment: A picture of the open panel would help.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I have one of these: https://www.princessauto.com/en/detail/mini-digital-clamp-meter/A-p8344707e

Comment: Hydro dam is in progress, but not yet complete. No other power sources I’m aware of.

Comment: @Chris -- try clamping it around the service neutral in your panel, with the main breaker OFF, and seeing if you get a measurable current reading.  (If you can't get at the service neutral, you can also try the grounding electrode conductor exiting your panel, unless you have more than one of those, of course)

Comment: @Kris Will add a picture a bit later today.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Will do later today, the service input is behind an additional section I’ve never removed, but I will be brave and get wife to stand behind me with a 2x4.

Comment: Was this the main ground wire (grounding electrode conductor)? Did you remove the neutral-ground bond before you removed the ground wire?

Answer (score -1):

An inductive load and a capacitor (e.g. motor start capacitor) are the principal pieces to store energy for a shock after disconnecting service. No idea if it actually happens in practice.